# Como copiar um arquivo com PHP?

Tags: php

Bom o meu problema é o seguinte desejo imprimir um código PHP em outro arquivo.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um arquivo `x.php`, e tenho um arquivo `y.php`, neste arquivo `y.php` quero que este crie um arquivo `z.php` e que faça uma cópia ao arquivo `x.php`, Como posso fazê-lo?

Answer (score 3):

Bem, se for para fazer cópia de um arquivo .php utilize a função copy() do php: 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.copy.php

```
$arquivo = 'arquivo.php';
$copia   = 'copia.php';

if (!copy($arquivo, $copia)) {
    echo "falha ao copiar $arquivo...\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para copiares em PHP, conforme já referido, podes usar a função [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) que te permite copiar um ficheiro para outro local ou para outro ficheiro pois o nome de entrada não tem que ser igual ao nome de saída.

### Exemplo

Conteúdo do arquivo `x.php`

```
<?php
// Eu sou o arquivo X

echo "X é muita fixe, mas o bubu é mais fixe!";
?>
```

Conteúdo do arquivo `y.php`

```
<?php
// Eu sou o arquivo Y

// Vou criar um arquivo "z.php" e copiar para lá o arquivo "x.php"
copy("caminho/para/arquivo/x.php", "caminho/para/arquivo/z.php");
?>
```

O resultado daquilo que o arquivo `y.php` faz é criar um arquivo com o nome `z.php` que irá conter o conteúdo do arquivo `x.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode incluir códigos PHP dentro de outro utilizando os comandos *include*, *require* e *require_once*. O  melhor no seu caso é o include, que pode ser utilizado assim:

```
include('arquivo.php');
```

Se lembre que o arquivo a ser chamado deve estar no mesmo diretório que o arquivo atual, caso esteja em outra pasta, ou em uma pasta anterior, você precisa especificar exatamente o caminho, exemplos:

```
include('scripts/arquivo.php'); // Arquivo em uma pasta que está dentro do diretório atual
include('../arquivo.php'); // Arquivo em um diretório antes
```

Para saber a diferença entre os comandos você pode dar uma pesquisada. Aqui uma referência rápida: https://webpub.wordpress.com/2007/11/11/diferenca-entre-require-require_once-include-include_once/

Comment: Por exemplo, eu tenho um arquivo x.php, e tenho um arquivo y.php, neste arquivo y.php quero que este crie um arquivo z.php e que faça uma cópia ao arquivo x.php, Como posso faze-lo?